# Taking data from inside Ajax Jsonp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I want to receive data from inside Ajax function(result).

Why doesn't work this app?

Please Help.

```
function star(a) {
    var res;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api-metrica.yandex.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?end-date=today&ids=ga%3A35416355&dimensions=ga:pagePath&metrics=ga:users&filters=ga:pagePath==/p/etkinlikler.html&start-date=2015-10-25&oauth_token=AQAAAAAVs-uLAASpEAf-MmJK_kHgpU9Fwv8WArM',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            res = result.totalsForAllResults["ga:users"];
        }
    });

    return res;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q6vfgemp/

Comment: `async: false,` ... JSONP can **NOT** be synchronous, ever, at all - so see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Result is "invalid token". Is this the text you want to be taking?

Comment: I thought the point of jsonp was you told the endpoint what javascript method the response should call, so you'd have access to the data inside that method...

Answer (score 0):

It's working , But you need to move that line :

```
$("div").html(res);
```

inside success function

Comment: I know but that's not what I want.

Comment: I want to outside success function and ajax.